# pan gesture after rotation behaves incorrect

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have similar question as in below link

[Why I use "pan" after rotae will make view go opposite way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707001/why-i-use-pan-after-rotae-will-make-view-go-opposite-way)

But, this link also didn't solved my problem.
I am using pan, pinch and rotation gesture for same UIImage. When, i rotate that image, and performs pan, it will give random panning(sometimes it goes in opposite direction of panning. I also set anchor point to (0.5,0.5)). But, if i only use pan (i.e. before rotation) it will perform well as expected.
How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: good question, I sadly have the same problem. Did you have any solution?

Comment: Not yet. Even i tried pan via touches move but still it behaves incorrect after using rotate gesture on same image.

Comment: ok if I find the solution, I will post it here. Therefore I took this question as favorite, so I will find it then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally solved this issue... You just need to change below code  `CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view];`to `CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:[gesture.view superview]];` present inside UIPanGestureRecognizer method.

OR follow below link
http://cs354dory.wordpress.com/code-examples/pinch-pan-and-rotate/

Comment: same effect like my code :) I checked your code, too. Nice and finally we both found the solution :)

Comment: wowowowowowowowowowowowowoowowowowowow thank UUUuuuuuuuUUUUu !!!!!!!!!!!!!! i have same problem for a long time.  my stress reach the climax....! your angel !!!! thank you

Answer (score 1):

I solved it,too.

Just put these 2 lines of code into the rotationfunction.

```
gestureRecognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(gestureRecognizer.view.transform, gestureRecognizer.rotation);
gestureRecognizer.rotation = 0;
```