# Image moving while rotating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I just move sticker after rotate, but the direction of the moved sticker is changed as much as the rotation angle and moves

please help me, i don't know why this happen

panGesture:

```
UIView *gestureView = gesture.view;
CGPoint point = [gesture translationInView:gestureView];

// react native 단에서 쓰레기 위치를 바텀 기준 10%로 잡음
// height은 top 기준
double trashBottomPosition = round(self.bounds.size.height * 0.90);
double trashCenterPosition = round(self.bounds.size.width / 2);
            
double nextXPosition = gestureView.center.x + (_currentTextScale * point.x);
double nextYPosition = gestureView.center.y + (_currentTextScale  * point.y);
bool isXTrashArea = trashCenterPosition - 40 < nextXPosition && trashCenterPosition + 40 > nextXPosition;
bool isYTrashArea = trashBottomPosition - 40 < nextYPosition && trashBottomPosition + 40 > nextYPosition;
            
switch (gesture.state) {

    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        break;
    
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
    {
        if (isXTrashArea && isYTrashArea) {
           _openTrash = true;
           if (!_isScaleDown && _isTrashMode) {
               _prevScale = gestureView.transform.a;
               gestureView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
               _isScaleDown = true;
           }
    } else {
        _openTrash = false;
                        
        if (_isScaleDown && _isTrashMode) {
             gestureView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(_prevScale, _prevScale);
             _isScaleDown = false;
        }
    }
                    
    gestureView.center = CGPointMake(nextXPosition, nextYPosition);
                    
                    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:gestureView];

                    break;
                }
                case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
                    if (_openTrash && _isTrashMode) {
                        [gestureView removeFromSuperview];
                    }
                    
                    _openTrash = false;
                    break;
                }
                    
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

rotate:

```
UIView *gestureView = gesture.view;
            if (_isActiveText) return;
            
            switch (gesture.state) {
                case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
                    gestureView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
                    break;
                }
                    
                case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
                {
        //            CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:self];
                    
                    
                    gestureView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(gestureView.transform, gesture.rotation);
                    _currentTextRotate = gesture.rotation;
                    gesture.rotation = 0;

                    break;
                }
                case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
                    
                    break;
                }
                    
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

add image:

bool isNetwork = [RCTConvert BOOL:[sticker objectForKey:@"isNetwork"]];
bool isAsset = [RCTConvert BOOL:[sticker objectForKey:@"isAsset"]];

```
        NSString *uri = [sticker objectForKey:@"uri"];
        NSString *type = [sticker objectForKey:@"type"];

        NSURL *url = isNetwork || isAsset
          ? [NSURL URLWithString:uri]
          : [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:uri ofType:type]];
        
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: img];
        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(150, 150, 130, 130);
        imgView.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        imgView.multipleTouchEnabled = true;

        
        // rotation
        UIRotationGestureRecognizer *stickerRotationGestureRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(stickerRotationGesture:)];
        stickerRotationGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [imgView addGestureRecognizer:stickerRotationGestureRecognizer];
        
        
        // pan gesture
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *stickerPanGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(stickerPanGesture:)];
        [stickerPanGestureRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
        [stickerPanGestureRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
        stickerPanGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [imgView addGestureRecognizer:stickerPanGestureRecognizer];
        
        
        // pinch
        UIPinchGestureRecognizer *stickerPinchGestureRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(stickerPinchGesture:)];
        stickerPinchGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [imgView addGestureRecognizer:stickerPinchGestureRecognizer];
        
        // longpress stickerLongPressGesture
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *stickerLongPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(stickerLongPressGesture:)];
        stickerLongPressGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        stickerLongPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.02;
        [imgView addGestureRecognizer:stickerLongPressGestureRecognizer];

        
        [self addSubview:imgView];
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: May be there is big empty space below image in the imageview?

Comment: thank you for answering my question.


additionally, i write here, add image  code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525922/pan-gesture-after-rotation-behaves-incorrect